# Почему сравнение при помощи == двух экземпляров класса с одинаковыми данными возвращает False?

Tags: python

```
class Obj:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b


if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj1 = Obj(1, 2)
    obj2 = Obj(1, 2)
    print(obj1 == obj2) # False
```

Comment: Потому что физически это два разных объекта. Если вам нужно, чтобы можно было проверять по равенству полей, то вам нужно переопределить метод `__eq__`

Comment: а что вы сравниваете, вы подумали? адреса объектов класса? выведете  на печать obj1 и obj2 и посмотрите.

Comment: `print(obj1.a == obj2.a)`